# Finding points a certain distance from each other

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I would like to find the maximum amount of points within a specified domain that are a certain distance from each other. For example, how many points within an area are 1000ft from each other? I envision each point with a radius of the desired distance, but I don't know if I must start with a point or what.

Comment: Welcome @Laura to GIS SE, can you update your example?

Comment: Sorry, yes. For example, how many points within an area are 1000ft from each other. I envision each point with a radius of the desired distance, but I don't know if I must start with a point or what.

Comment: It's hard to see what an answer to your question would look like, Laura.  The criterion ("a certain distance from each other") applies to point *pairs,* not to points, so in what sense does counting just points relate to that criterion?

Comment: I see what you mean. Say, I have a plot of land and I want to fit the maximum amount of benches in the allotted space but they cannot be within 1000ft of any of them - I guess not within a 1000ft radius.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me that you would get an answer to your question by creating a subset of your points dataset and running Near analysis (if you're using ArcGIS) on it subset choosing it as both: near and input features. [Description of that tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001q000000.htm). Having done this you would be able to choose points that have a neighbor in the same dataset within certain distance.

Answer (score 1):

Just from the sound of it, you want to pick a point and buffer it 1000ft, then give a total of how many points are within that buffer.  Is that correct?  If, so you just need to loop through each point and buffer it a 1000ft, then take the buffer and do a spatial query, could be a within or contains, to get the total count.  I do not know if you are using ArcGIS, QGIS, etc., but basically that is the process.

1. Buffer point of interest
2. Use buffer geometry to perform a spatial query to get count of points within
   the geometry
3. Repeat until finished.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in a Python implementation of what Jamie suggests, try running this code (adjust paths to data accordingly in lines 4,5,8,9,10):

<del>*note: untested*</del> **Tested/Confirmed**

```
import arcpy

# buffer points
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/GIS/temp"
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("pointData.shp", "C:/GIS/temp/pointDataBuffer.shp", "1000 Feet", "#", "#", "NONE")

# spatial join and count the number of points falling inside of each buffer
target_features = "C:/GIS/temp/pointdataBuffer.shp"
join_features = "C:/GIS/temp/pointData.shp"
out_feature_class = "C:/GIS/temp/pointDataBufferJoin.shp"

arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features, join_features, out_feature_class)
```

The join_count field which is created in your pointsDataBufferJoin file will tell you how many points matched up ("Intersected") with each 1000 foot buffer.