# Using ArcPy to find all points that lie within certain radius of other points?

Tags: arcpy, proximity

I am trying to find a way to count all the points that are only within a specified distance of 500 meters of another set of points.

My first shapefile contains a series of points of various types of businesses in an area. And the other shapefile contains only points of churches in the same area. I want to overlay the two shapefiles programmatically using python to determine how many of my original set of points lie within a 500 radius of the church points.

I've attempted to solve this is but I am running into a few problems. First is I am not sure how to extract a particular type of business from my shapefile, say barbershops, I am not sure how I would specify to python that I only want to find the number of barbershops that lie within a radius 500 Meters of all Churches in the area.

Here is what I am attempting:

```
import arcpy


# Unsure what exactly Buffer_analysis does, so not sure if this would work
arypy.Buffer_analysis("LocalBusinesses.shp", "C:\Users\new\pointDataBuffer.shp", "500 Meters", "#", "#", "NONE")

target_features = "C:\Users\new\churches.shp"

join_features = "C:\Users\new\LocalBusinesses.shp"

out_features = "C:\Users\new\pointDataBuffer.shp"

arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features, join_features, out_features,"#","#","#","#","500 Meters","#")
```

Problems I am facing are to specific that I only want barbershops in the first shapefile. I am not sure if 500 Meters there will take care of that.

Is there a more efficient way of performing this?

Wasn't sure how to use this info, but it seems relevant:

- [Finding points that are within a set distance of other points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91571/finding-points-that-are-within-a-set-distance-of-other-points)
- [Finding points a certain distance from each other](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19551/finding-points-a-certain-distance-from-each-other)

Also wondering if this might work:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Point_Distance/00080000001r000000/

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a total count of Points within 500 meters, run "Select by Location", select "Intersect the source layer feature" , enable "Apply a search distance", enter 500 for the distance and "Meters" for the unit.

Comment: Thanks klewis, but I am trying to write this into a python script. I just found the arcpy function SelectLayerByAttribute_management. Therefore I think I could use that to isolate only barbershops, but not sure how to filer/restrict it to 500 meters.

Comment: My mistake! I see that feature now. Will try it. Thank you